# Date parsing issue in the where clause in Snowflake query

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowsql

I am running a Snowflake query that is intended to return records that among other things, have a date earlier than the current date.

```
select *
from table_a
where id < 100 and
date < ???
```

The problem is, the data this query is running on has issues in the date column. For example, one value may be a single digit (like `2`). I don't want the query to break on those rows. That's why I'm looking to write a `case` in the `where` clause to only consider records that have their date as `YYYY-MM-DD`. I tried the following, but it is returning syntax errors:

```
and date = case WHEN date like '____-__-__' then date < current_date() else NULL
```

Also

```
and date < case WHEN date like '____-__-__' then current_date() else NULL
```

(In case it's not visible due to formatting, that is 4 underscores - meaning any character, followed by one dash, followed by 2 underscores, then a dash, and then another two underscores.)

You can assume `current_date()` has no issues. It can even be replaced with some hard-coded value if needed.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TRY_TO_DATE(date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` as it tries to converts it to date and when invalid format it will turn automatically to NULL

So, you can apply a filter is not NULL beside the date comparison.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression for this

```js
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '2020-05-12' AS string) a where REGEXP_LIKE(string,'\\d{4,4}\\-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}');
```

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-snowflake-regular-expression

Comment: The solution shared by Monem is more elegant